Emacs calc: Switch two rows
I am using Emacs calc. I want to switch the contents of two rows. For instance:
5. 10
4. 20
3. 30
2. 40
1. 50

I want "50" to be in row number 4 and "20" to be in row number 1. Basically, swap them around.
I wasn't able to find this in the documentation. The Stack Manipulation article, describes how to swap rows that are next to one another, but not how to swap items that might be separated by many rows.
Is there a simple command of function to do this?

Whilst it is not "switching" rows, I found this approach to be even more convenient.
If you press backquote (`), you can edit the top of the stack on a separate buffer.
However, if you prefix the backquote with a numer (Ctrl U + <n> +  ), you can edit n entries. In that way, you can switch the entries using this editing mode.

Mark one entry with C-<space>, go to the other entry and say C-0 C-x C-t. The function is calc-transpose-lines and its doc string says:
...
 With argument 0, switch line point is in with line mark is in.
...


Oh, I see. Is there a function that prompts for two rows to be switched? That would be a great answer. If we can't come up with anything else, I'll mark your answer. Thank you very much in advance.

No such function exists: it would be way too specialized to be generally useful.

@NickD: On my installation calc-transpose-lines is bound to  C-x C-t , not C-c C-t .

Indeed - fixed.
